# ASP.NET MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

What would be the most appropriate route for this URL?

```
www.mysite.com/searchkey0

www.mysite.com/searchkey1
```

Where `searchkey` is the keyword for a search method? I tried the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
        "SearchRoute", _
        "search", _
        New With {.controller = "Search", .action = "Search", .id = ""} _
   )
```

In this route, the URL must have `/search/searchkey`. I only want to have the `searchkey` in the URL, and not the word `Search`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please mark the answer that helped you as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
        "SearchRoute", _
        "{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Search", .action = "Search", .id = ""} _
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

to see what route your mvc is using have alook at this tool

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

hth

bones